# Why the "lspci" command does not list the serial ports?

Tags: linux, serial-port, x86, pci

I have enabled two serial ports in VirtualBox, and then typed the `lspci` command in Ubuntu, and this is the result:

[image]

The serial ports are not listed, is it because the serial ports are not part of the PCI bus?

Comment: yes.  try `sudo lshw -html > ~/Desktop/hardware.html` and then view that file in your browser. it will show you *all* the hardware info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it because the serial ports are not part of the PCI bus?

Yes. Traditional PC serial ports on x86 hardware interface with applications via old-style ISA I/O ports and interrupts.

Keep in mind that RS-232 data rates are down in the kHz range in the vast majority of cases. PCI holds no advantage for RS-232.

Add-on PCI serial port cards may appear in `lspci` output, but that's more about available slots than the appropriateness of PCI to RS-232.

Answer (score 1):

The "why" has already been answered, but let me add that you can list the serial ports on the ISA bus with `lspnp` (if you have it installed):

```
$ /sbin/lspnp
00:00 PNP0c01 System board
00:01 PNP0c02 Motherboard resources
...
00:09 PNP0501 16550A-compatible serial port
...
```

You will also find these in `/sys/bus/pnp/devices/`, or you can look at the I/O ports (`/proc/ioports`) or the memory mapped I/O (`/proc/iomem`) as root.

The old-style ISA bus is actually implemented as [LPC bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Pin_Count) or current computers, and will become [eSPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) in the future.